# How to save data and then share it with React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am beginner to building Apps with React Native + Redux.
I am trying to create an App family budget. It's almost done.
BUT I have two questions for them who already created these kind of apps.

1. **What is the best way to save data?**  I want to save it (data: expenses/dates/category etc) on devices iOS (not database) if it's possible. I think it does not take a lot of memory. I've read about AsyncStorage, but not sure about it. Is it still present after reloading App/Phone?
2. **How to share data between two users?** I want to make a function, like sharing the budget between family members.

I will be very grateful for the recommendations and suggestions, maybe even for some good articles with explanation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using redux, you can use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to store your state on devices.
2. To share data between devices, you probably need to implement a remote server (cloud), which receives budget changes and propagates them to other family members.

Comment: Thanks Tim. So if I need to implement a remote server then redux-persist loses its usefulness? Or they are independent of each other?

Comment: @Vova no, you can still store the budget on device. Of course you need a way to synchronize the "cloud budget" with the offline stored budget on the devices and update the local storage if necessary.

Comment: Tim I've already upvoted) I haven't accepted yet because I am in process of find out more about your answer. Thanks again